# secure SSL VPN between two private IP Addresses through a public VPS on Internet

Tags: vpn, private-network

Is it possible to establish a secure SSL VPN connection as shown below? :

Computer A (192.168.1.20) <-> ISP 1 (192.168.1.1) <-> public IP Address of VPS <-> ISP 2 (172.20.164.6) <-> Computer B (172.20.164.174)

Both Computers A and B are assigned **private IP Addresses** by their ISP. I have full control on Computers A and B and also VPS.

Answer (score 0):

VPN connections need to be on both sides and set to connect to the other much like shown in this  AWS VPC documentation.

[Secure VPN across Domains](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Security.html)